# Unital Banach Algebras such that $\|a\|<1$ and $\|b\|<1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-algebras

The following question is from my exercise sheet in Banach Algebras and I am not able to solve 1 part.

Question: Let $A$ be a Banach Algebra with $1$.

(a) Let $a,b\in A$, then show that $1-ab$ is invertible iff $1-ba$ is invertible.

(b) Let $a,b$ be such that $\|a\|<1$ and $\|b\|<1$. Show that $1-ab $ and $1-ba$ are invertible in $A$.

Attempt: I have shown (a) using the following obeservation: if $1−ab$  has inverse $x$ , then $1−ba$  has inverse $1+bxa$.

But I am not able to prove (b) part.

Can you please tell me how should I approach this part?

Comment: Notice that in a Banach Algebra: $||ab||\le ||a||.||b||$.

Comment: And I think this link helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814312/is-an-invertible-element-in-a-banach-algebra-always-within-a-certain-neighborhoo

Comment: The standard trick is to observe that  $(1-x)\left (1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right )=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much for the hint. I have shown what was asked.